# How to get the reason for process start in android program?

Tags: android, process, activity-manager

I can see some log like this:

```
 Start proc com.**.** for activity com.**.**/com.**.**: pid=11091 uid=10146 gids={50146, 3003, 1028, 1015} by log Tag ActivityManager.
```

So, I want to know, how can i get the activity's class name in the process

Comment: you actually hide it yourself what you are looking around ? could you please comment on @pcconcepcion answer ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, in that same line you have the full name of the Activity class:

**for activity com.**.**/com.**.****:

Is not that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i want to get it in program

Answer (score 0):

my problem has little different with you. I wish to know

```
is some Activity cause the UI process start?
```

especially the LAUNCHER actitity.

My app's UI process has many ways to launch, e.g drag by ContentProvider/Service/Activity, I only want to know if the originator was LAUNCHER activity.

So I hack The `ActivityThread#H`, the main entry to recieve the launch activity message. when I done the Application's onCreate() job, I post delay a task about 1 second then check whether that Handler receive those message or not, if so, I consider the UI process was drag by Activity, finally I take the answer.

Hope It can inspire you.